# How does the Unix kernel convert a file offset?

Tags: unix, filesystems, kernel, offset, ext2

As the title suggests, i'm having trouble figuring out how the Unix kernel converts a logical file offset into a logical block number and then retrieves it from the i-node.

As a reference, i'm asking a more detailed explanation of the "bmap" algorithm described first in "The Design of the UNIX Operating System" by Maurice J. Bach.

Thank you..

Comment: Generally, that mapping is basically the raison d'être for a *file system* - mapping the directory hierarchy and file data to representations and ranges in the flat block device. I'm not familiar with the original UNIX, so I'm afraid I can't help with specifics.

Comment: @pmjordan : thank you. I'm not necessarily asking for information about the unix file system, also talking about the ext2 would be fine with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I unfortunately can't help you with the original implementation of UNIX; but the job of mapping the high-level directory hierarchy to an on-disk representation, and for assigning ranges on the bare block device to files normally falls to one or more *file systems*. The POSIX spec makes some high-level demands on the file system, but what actually ends up on disk is completely specific to each file system.

The ext2 file system is comparatively simple, but a detailed explanation of it still fills an entire chapter of a book - one such book is *Understanding the Linux Kernel* by Daniel P. Bovet and Marco Cesati.

A more brief, higher-level introductory text comes with the Linux kernel itself, and [can also be found here](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext2.txt). That directory also contains [documentation on other Linux file systems](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/) and also the "VFS" layer, which handles a lot of the higher-level aspects which are common to all or most file systems. [Wikipedia's ext2 article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2) also covers it at a high level. It also provides some links to more detailed online descriptions.

This is unfortunately not a topic that will fit in a SO answer, but I hope the above pointers help to get you started.